# How to calculate z position of ImageTarget with screen and AR Camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new Unity3d and Vuforia. I am developing AR project with Unity3d and Vuforia. I want to show found target object when they lost. I can show them, but they wrong position for some devices. I want to scale all game object by them's z position.

**Note:**

1. World Center Mode: CAMERA
2. Using ImageTarget of Vuforia

I want calculate z position of ImageTarget fit with screen and AR Camera. How to do it?